# ClassCastException ContentFrameLayout androidx vs. support.v7 in system app

Tags: android, android-source, androidx

Strange Exception I am getting on a system app when I am using just `FrameLayout` in my `SampleActivity`.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout cannot be cast to android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout
05-22 08:41:05.357 10520 10520 E AndroidRuntime: at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:685)
05-22 08:41:05.357 10520 10520 E AndroidRuntime: at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:516)
05-22 08:41:05.357 10520 10520 E AndroidRuntime: at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:464)
05-22 08:41:05.357 10520 10520 E AndroidRuntime: at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
05-22 08:41:05.357 10520 10520 E AndroidRuntime: at com.sample.SampleActivity.onCreate(SampleActivity.java:98)
```

So I looked into the source code of `AppCompatDelegateImpl` present here : [AppCompatDelegateImpl](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/master/v7/appcompat/src/main/java/androidx/appcompat/app/AppCompatDelegateImpl.java)

imports in `SampleActivity.java`:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
```

While this class is part of android `appcompat.v7` but internally it is importing `androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout` Does it imply that appcompat.v7 internally use androidx dependencies ? If yes, then why I am getting this exception ?

**Note**: Please avoid giving gradle based solutions since it is a system app.

Comment: add gradle files

Comment: @Basi It's a system application not the regular one, so it doesn't have gradle.

Comment: Share the full code of your activity. If possible share the repository link.

Comment: Sorry that I can't do. You can ask me any specific code you're looking for, I'll share. @BelalKhan

Comment: Then atleast post the full activity code here. Or the line where you are trying to make a cast.

Comment: @Belal Consider reading the question and the error log. I am nowhere using that ContentFrameLayout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix was to include androidx dependencies in `Android.mk` file.

Also had to change all import of support library classes to androidx as suggested in Android developer site: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate

Answer (score 1):

Go to **gradle.properties** file and make sure

```
android.useAndroidX=false
```

If you set this to **true**, android plugin will use AndroidX Library instead of Support Library. Furthermore, if you're unable to find **useAndroidX** in **gradle.properties**, try adding it and perform gradle sync.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto The **ContentFrameLayout** you have inside SampleActivity is part of [androidx.appcompat.widget](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/master/v7/appcompat/src/main/java/androidx/appcompat/widget/ContentFrameLayout.java). The **ContentFrameLayout** you need is inside [android.support.v7.widget](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/8c3f757/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/widget/ContentFrameLayout.java). Try using `import android.widget.FrameLayout;` and see if it links to support library.

Comment: I am using this FrameLayout only.

Answer (score 0):

Update your import statements. You're using class with same name but from different packages.

Comment: What do you mean ? Please note that I am nowhere using "ContentFrameLayout"